# Whats the meaning of this" vector(vector'HIGH)='1'"?

Tags: vhdl

I know 'HIGH its a data attribute, that return the upper array index, but the vector out side the parentheses i dont get it. Its the same as vector'HIGH??

Tell me if someone need more info or something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's go by parts:

- `vector'high`: if used on an array, the attribute 'high returns the highest value that can be used to index into that array. A more formal definition is: it's the [highest subscript of array A or constrained array type](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html). So if `vector` has range (7 downto 0), `vector'high` equals 7
- `vector( X )`: returns the value of the element at position X in `vector` (this is trivial array indexing)
- so, `vector( vector'high )` returns the value of the element with the highest subscript in `vector`
- finally `vector(vector'high)='1'` is comparing that element's value against the literal bit value '1'.

To give a concrete example, if you have:

```
constant vector: standard_logic_vector(7 downto 0) = "1000_000X";
```

then:

`vector(vector'high)` will be equal `'1'`

Personally, I think it would be great if we had a predefined attribute for that (returning the *value* of the element with the highest subscript).

Finally, for the sake of completeness, `'high` can be used with constrained arrays (seems to be your case) or with types. If used on a type identifier, it will provide the highest value of that type. For example: `bit'high` --> `'1'`, `std_logic'high` --> `'-'`.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a normal index into the vector.

`vector'high` gives you a number which is defined to be the highest bit position in the vector.

So like `vector(2)` gives you the bit in position 2 of the vector, so `vector(vector'high)` returns the value in the highest bit.

Answer (score 2):

It compares the element of the highest subscript in `vector` with `'1'`. For comparison, `vector(3)` would be the vector's element that happens to have the subscript 3.